# Receive all elements of database with npm orm

Tags: node.js, orm

I use the [npm orm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/orm) and I already can create new database entries. Now I want to receive all entries but it does not work as expected. I used the `.all` function to receive the entries but it didn't work.

**app**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var orm = require('orm');

var db = orm.connect('mysql://root:fdB2bJ6p@localhost/iDanGManagement', function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = db;

var Person = db.define('person', {
  id:     { type: 'serial', key: true },
  name:   { type: 'text' },
  email:  { type: 'text' }
});

// views
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


// join public dir
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// parse stuff
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  Person.all(function(err, persons) {
    if(err) return err;
    console.log(persons, persons.name)
  });
  res.render('index');
});

app.post('/add', function(req, res) {
  var new_person = {};
  new_person.name = req.body.name;
  new_person.email = req.body.email;
  Person.create(new_person, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

When I print `persons.name` I simply receive *undefined*. The output of persons:

```
[ { id: [Getter/Setter],
    name: [Getter/Setter],
    email: [Getter/Setter] } ]
```

Plus I receive no Errors. Do you guys know why this does not work?

Comment: That is returning an array, which looks correct to me, how many persons do you have in your database?  Try `console.log(persons[0].name)`.

Comment: @RichardMacarthy this gives me one wanted result. But how can I get every entry? For testing purposes I just got 3 entries

Comment: You need to loop through the array, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Person.find({}, function(err, persons) {
    if(err) return err;
    console.log(persons, persons.length);
});
```

Or even:

```
Person.find(function(err, persons) {
    if(err) return err;
    console.log(persons, persons.length);
});
```

Does this work for you?

EDIT*

Loop through persons:

```
Person.all(function(err, persons) {
    persons.forEach(function(person){
        console.log(person);
    });
});
```

Comment: Iv'e edited the answer, what does err and persons return respectively?